# Why does my CSV file read as "UTF-8" but is actually "Latin-1"

Tags: python, pandas, csv, encoding

The output of my code says the encoding is "UTF-8". However, it turns out that my file's encoding is actually "Latin-1". Why is this the case?

Input:

```py
with open("laptops.csv") as l:
    print(l)

import pandas as pd
laptops = pd.read_csv("laptops.csv", encoding="UTF-8")
print(laptops)
```

Output:

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='laptops.csv' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-c399168ffe6d> in <module>
      3 
      4 import pandas as pd
----> 5 laptops = pd.read_csv("laptops.csv", encoding="UTF-8")
      6 print(laptops)
...

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 132936: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: Can we see the code where you decode the data?

Comment: Your file must contain some data which does not conform to UTF-8.

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: Following what @tadman said, check out this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: @DanielWalker Sorry I don't really understand your comment. I'm very new to this. Do you mean 'show me the full error message'? I only know that the csv file is "Latin-8" encoding because it was a file provided by Dataquest and they informed the encoding of the file.

Comment: Python will open a text file with an assumed encoding, even if that encoding is wrong.  Since you don't actually try to read the file until `read_csv` there's no earlier opportunity to encounter the error.

Comment: To expand on my comment, the output `encoding='UTF-8'` doesn't actually mean that the file is UTF-8, only that that's what Python *assumed* when it opened it.  If that assumption was wrong you may get an error if you try to read the file, but you never read the file until you opened it a second time in `read_csv`.

Comment: Alright @MarkRansom. Understand that Python is assuming the encoding. Finding out the encoding may be a little complex for my level

Comment: You don't need to find out the encoding, you were told by the producer of the file - that's the way it should always be done.  Now all you have to do is substitute the parameter in the `read_csv` call.

Comment: @MarkRansom That way sounds much more convenient! Thank you!

Comment: If you say your file uses `Latin-1`, then YOU must specify this when opening the file. e.g. `with open("laptops.csv", encoding='latin-1')`, likewise with `read_csv()`